# Calculating growth rate

Tags: exponential-function

Let's say I want to have saved $200 in one year.

The first week I afford to save $1.

I'm curious to find out how the calculation would look like to understand the following:

*By how much would I need to increment the savings each week to reach a total of $200 after 52 weeks?*

Comment: What have you tried? Also, what is the context of this problem? Is there interest involved?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, because I have no idea how to calculate this. And no, there would not be any interest involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could think of it as $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{51}1+ix=200$ or $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{52}1+(i-1)x=200$

Because you're looking to solve $1+(1+x)+(1+2x)+\dots+(1+51x)=200$ for x, right?